# Simultaneous calls

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, intervals

I'm trying to calculate the number of simultaneous calls at the time a particular call is made by looking at the datetime ranges. My query works, but takes ~10 minutes to perform for only 95,000 records, which is too long. Any ideas for optimization?

```
SELECT r.*,
       rr.ChannelsActive  'ChannelsActive'
FROM #rg r
OUTER APPLY
(
      SELECT SUM(1) AS ChannelsActive
      FROM #rg r_inner 
      WHERE 
      (
             r_inner.CallStart BETWEEN r.CallStart AND r.CallEnd 
            OR r_inner.CallEnd BETWEEN r.CallStart AND r.CallEnd
            OR r.CallStart BETWEEN r_inner.CallStart AND r_inner.CallEnd 
            OR r.CallEnd BETWEEN r_inner.CallStart AND r_inner.CallEnd

      )
 ) rr
```

Example Data

```
CREATE TABLE #rg
  (
     CallStart DATETIME,
     CallEnd   DATETIME
  )

CREATE INDEX ix1
  ON #rg(CallStart, CallEnd)

CREATE INDEX ix2
  ON #rg(CallEnd, CallStart);

WITH T(N, R)
     AS (SELECT TOP (95000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RN,
                            ABS(120 + 30 * SQRT(-2 * LOG(ABS(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS BIGINT) AS FLOAT) / 9223372036854775807))) * COS(2 * PI() * ABS(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS BIGINT) AS FLOAT) / 9223372036854775807)))
         FROM   sys.all_objects o1,
                sys.all_objects o2)
INSERT INTO #rg
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, N, GETDATE()),
       DATEADD(SECOND, N + R, GETDATE())
FROM   T
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The condition is equivalent to: `r_inner.CallStart <= r.CallEnd AND r.CallStart <= r_inner.CallEnd` (assuming that Start<=End in all rows in both tables.)

Comment: This article by Itzik Ben-Gan seems to be written for your case: **[Interval Queries in SQL Server](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/sql-server-interval-queries)**

Comment: ypercube - That worked perfectly. Cut it down from 10 minutes to 4 minutes and 30 seconds.

Comment: That converts it  from a cross join where it scans all the rows each time to a triangular join where on average it scans half. Maybe you could use something [like this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14894/optimizing-ip-range-search/14896#14896) to reduce it further. Are you always calculating it for the whole table?

Comment: @user172839  Are you aware that this query does not in fact "*calculate the number of simultaneous calls at the time a particular call is made*"?  What it actually calculates is the "*total number of calls whose timespan overlaps the timespan of the subject call*", which is a very different thing.  Is that what you meant or is this query incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
 ;WITH cteCallEvents As
 (
        SELECT *, CallStart As EventTime, 1 As EventType FROM #rg r
    UNION ALL
        SELECT *, CallEnd   As EventTime, 0 As EventType FROM #rg r
 )
 , cteCallCounts As
 (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By EventTime) as EventCount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By EventType Order By EventTime) as TypeCount
    FROM cteCallEvents
 )
 SELECT *,
    2*TypeCount - EventCount  As OpenCalls
FROM    cteCallCounts
WHERE   EventType = 1
```

It should take a couple of seconds at most.  Should work on any SQL Server 2005+.

Comment: +1 This is very fast on my example data. To return exactly the same as the query in the OP it looks like the formula would be `1 + EventCount - TypeCount`. Maybe your formula is more sensible though. Too late in the day for me to think about that one!

Comment: Both don't return the expected results. Can you please explain how you are trying to solve the solution as I haven't been able to decipher the query yet!

Comment: @user172839 Sorry, I was counting the open calls at the end of the call instead of the beginning.  I will correct now, and provide an explanation a little but later (can't ignore the family too much on the holiday here).

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the much needed help.

Comment: I realised my original solution was incorrect. For example, say Call 1 was between 10:30 and 10:50, Call 2 was 10:32-10:35, and Call 3 was between 10:40 and 10:42, the OpenCalls was been calculated as 3 for Call 1 where in reality it should be 2.

Comment: I've modified my solution and now the query is lightning fast. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL like this to get a list of start/end events...

```
Select CallStart, 1 As CallCount From #rg
Union All
Select CallEnd, -1 From #rg
Order By CallStart
```

...then treat this as a simple running totals problem, which is solved differently depending upon your SQL Server version or can be easily addressed in code if that's an option.

Comment: To get the number of calls active at any given time, just add "Where CallStart < @Time And CallEnd >= @Time" to each query in the above UNION -- then Sum(CallCount) will give you the answer you want.