# Find the busiest period

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a large table in MS SQL 2012 (40m records) containing call data. I would like to find the peak volume of calls, and the time that it occurred. If possible, I would also like to find the next 4 busiest periods.

I plan to use 3 columns:
CallID
DialTime
EndTime

The only way I can think to do this would be to do this:

```
Select '2013-07-01 00:00:01' as [Period], count([CallID]) as [Calls]
from [Table]
where DialTime <= '2013-07-01 00:00:01'
and EndTime >= '2013-07-01 00:00:01'

union

Select '2013-07-01 00:00:02' as [Period], count([CallID]) as [Calls]
from [Table]
where DialTime <= '2013-07-01 00:00:02'
and EndTime >= '2013-07-01 00:00:02'

union

etc
```

Can anyone suggest a better/more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Related but not quite a duplicate as you are on 2012 and have a slightly different requirement. [Simultaneous calls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17441864/73226)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. `@time_begin` and `@time_end` are the parameters that you can use for the interval of time for which you want to get the results.

```
with time_items (time_item) as
(
    select @time_begin as time_item
    union all
    select dateadd(second,1,t.time_item) as time_item from time_items t where t.time_item<@time_end
)
select
    time_items.time_item as [Period],
    sum(case when [Table].DialTime<=time_items.time_item and [Table].EndTime>=time_items.time_item then 1 else 0 end) as [Calls]
from time_items
left outer join [Table] on 1=1
group by
    time_items.time_item
order by
    [Calls] desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use VALUES as Table Source

```
SELECT DialTime, EndTime, o.Calls
FROM (VALUES ('20130701 00:00:01', '20130701 00:00:01'),
             ('20130701 00:00:02', '20130701 00:00:02'))x(DialTime, EndTime)
  CROSS APPLY(
              SELECT COUNT(CallID) AS Calls      
              FROM [Table] t
              WHERE DialTime <= x.DialTime
                AND EndTime >= x.EndTime
              ) o
```