# Simultaneous Calls count in R

Tags: r

I would like to measure the simultaneous number of calls at any time on a telephony system. Nigh on identical to this [SQL example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441864/simultaneous-calls) but using R and a CSV file.

For a CSV file with Id (numeric), TimeOfCall(POSIXct), TimeOfClose(POSIXct) as the 3 column types I would do the following but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this in R (on a Windows machine)?

```
#Small dataset example. Much larger in reality
id <- c(1,2,3,4)

TimeOfStart <- c(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 10:10:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 10:14:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2013-03-01 10:10:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2013-03-01 10:20:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"))

TimeOfEnd <- c(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 10:20:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 10:44:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2013-03-01 10:21:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct("2013-03-01 10:25:00", format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"))

call_data <- data.frame(id, TimeOfStart, TimeOfEnd)

#holder for all POSIX converted to numeric entries
stringoftimes <- '0'

# loop through all rows and then concatenate all entries between start and end time after converting POSIX to numberics.
for (i in 1:nrow(call_data))  
{
    stringoftimes <- c(stringoftimes,c(as.numeric(call_data$TimeOfStart[i]):as.numeric(call_data$TimeOfStop[i])))

} 

#Convert to table so that count of entries takes place
stringoftimes <- as.data.frame(table(stringoftimes))

#Sort table to see highest results first
stringoftimes <- stringoftimes[order(stringoftimes$Freq, decreasing=TRUE),]
```

Comment: Example doesn't work because call_data$TimeOfCall/End should be TimeOfStart/Stop?

Comment: Thanks Spacedman, updated typo

Answer (score 0):

Howsabout this then:

Compute number of calls at this sequence of time points, by minutes:

```
> t = seq(min(call_data$TimeOfStart),max(call_data$TimeOfEnd),by=60)
```

Function is this:

```
> ncalls = Vectorize(function(t){sum(t>=call_data$TimeOfStart & t<=call_data$TimeOfEnd)})
```

Plot as a step function:

```
> plot(t,ncalls(t),type="s")
```

Comment: Thanks Spacedman. I've got an error saying that I cannot allocate vector size of 600+ Mb. I'll try you're method on a smaller subset of data.

Comment: Its probably generating a huge long vector of times. You can't expect to compute it every minute for ten years....